# Tkinter dropdown menu & MySql database input

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

first time posting here so not sure how this work, but here is the issue I'm currently on.
I'm making a database GUI application in python using Tkinter and MySQL.
I'm stuck on drop-down menus. The issue I'm having is that when I create a list or a dictionary for the drop-down menu I want it to be a word example(One) but when it's going to be entered in the database it should be a number e if that makes sense. Here is the code i have so far

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.errors import Error


root = Tk()
root.title("Account Tool 0.0.1a")
root.geometry("640x640")
# =======================================================================================================
account_db = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="root",
   passwd="123456",
   port="3310",
   database="realmd",
)
my_cursor = account_db.cursor()
exp_var = StringVar()
data = [
   "Mazda",
   "Volvo",
   "YUGO",
]

exp_var.set("Mazda")
# add acccount
def add_account():
   account = "INSERT INTO `account` (`id`, `username`, `sha_pass_hash`, `sessionkey`, `v`, `s`, `totp_secret`, `email`, `reg_mail`, `joindate`, `last_ip`, `last_attempt_ip`, `failed_logins`, `locked`, `lock_country`, `last_login`, `online`, `expansion`, `mutetime`, `mutereason`, `muteby`, `locale`, `os`, `recruiter`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
   v_account = (
   '', e_username.get(), e_password.get(), '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
   '', '', '', '', '',)

   my_cursor.execute(account, v_account)  # account_lvl, , v_account_lvl
   # commit to db
   account_db.commit()

# Labels
l_exp = Label(root, text="Car :").grid(row=1, column=1)  # drop down manu
l_username = Label(root, text="Username: ").grid(row=3, column=1)
l_passwd = Label(root, text="Password : ").grid(row=4, column=1)
# entry

drop_exp = ttk.OptionMenu(root, exp_var, *data)
drop_exp.grid(row=1, column=2)
e_username = Entry(root, width=20)
e_username.grid(row=3, column=2)
e_password = Entry(root, width=20)
e_password.grid(row=4, column=2)

# button

btn_create = Button(root, text="Create Account", command=add_account)
btn_create.grid(row=5, column=2)

# end window
root.mainloop()
```

p.s I know probably some of you will get a heart attack from my code but I started learning just recently thnx for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I've seen many worse questions :-).

The code needs to convert the text in StringVar to the appropriate numeric code.  There are many ways to do it below I've used a dictionary.

```
data ={'Mazda': 1234, 'Volvo': 567, 'YUGO': 2571 }

data.keys()
# dict_keys(['Mazda', 'Volvo', 'YUGO'])

list(data.keys())
# ['Mazda', 'Volvo', 'YUGO']

data['Volvo']
# 567
```

A small GUI as an example.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar( value = 'Mazda' )
labvar = tk.StringVar()

def do_read():
    print( data[var.get()] )
    labvar.set( data[var.get()] )

ttk.OptionMenu( root, var, 'Mazda', *data.keys() ).grid()
ttk.Label( root, textvariable = labvar).grid()
ttk.Button(root, text ='Click to read option.', command = do_read ).grid()

tk.mainloop()
```

I hope this is reasonably easy to understand. You can also trace a tk.StringVar to run a function whenever the StringVar changes.  This could be used to keep labvar and var synchronised but may confuse in the code here.

Comment: Thank you kind sir that worked for some reason :D, now im stuck with something else :'(